# Haskell - Searching the entire list for an char

Tags: list, function, haskell, haskell-platform

I have following list:

```
 charKeys=[('1','a')
          ,('2','b')
          ,('3','c')
          ,('4','d')
          ,('5','e')]
```

Now i want to search for an character in the list and replicate the other character three times.
I want a function like that:

```
 search x = if x == fst(charKeys !! 0) then replicate 3 (snd(charKeys !! 0)) else "Error"
```

But this function only check the first index of the list and works only for x == '1'.

Can somebody help me, that the function also works if x == '2' or '5' ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you familiar with recursive functions?  How about the `lookup` function?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, and for all of them we will be writing a function that also takes as an input `charKeys`.

The most important would be using recursion:

```hs
search n charKeys = if n == fst (head charKeys) then replicate 3 (snd (head charKeys)) else search n (tail charKeys)
```

We can rewrite this using pattern matching and function guards like so:

```hs
search n ((k,c):lst) | k == n       = replicate 3 c
                     | otherwise    = search n lst
```

It's also good practice to cover all possible inputs for a pattern match, so we add this additional line:

```hs
search _ [] = error "Requested key not found"
```

These are pretty important concepts in Haskell, so make sure you understand what's going on here before going on.

Another solution would be to use the function `find` from `Data.List`, documented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find):

```hs
import Data.List (find)
```

```hs
search n charKeys = case find ((==n) . fst) charKeys of
                        Just (_,c)  -> replicate 3 c
                        Nothing     -> error "Requested key not found"
```

Note that we're using a case statement to check whether we've found a matching element in the list, since `find` returns a `Maybe`.
Also, `(==n) . fst` is a more idiomatic way of saying `\x -> fst x == n`, using composition and operator punning.

We can simplify this even further by using Prelude's `lookup` function:

```hs
search n charKeys = case lookup n charKeys of
                        Just c  -> replicate 3 c
                        Nothing -> error "Requested key not found"
```

And even more by using `maybe` from `Data.Maybe` (also using `$`):

```hs
search n charKeys = maybe (error "Requested key not found") (replicate 3) $ lookup n charKeys
```